# How to debug my wordpress feed?

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, feed

I recently got involved with Wordpress - i am not so experienced with it so to speak. My RSS feed is broken. One cannot click the links to my articles anymore.

The Link URL looks like this: `/folder1/folder2/article`

As everyone can see, there is quite a lot missing, as it should look like so:

```
http://myUrl.org/folder1/folder2/article
```

My project is quite vast and i simply do not even know where to start looking for the failing URL construction. I believe our setup is quite standard.

There is e.g. the `feed-rss.php` file. This uses `<link><?php bloginfo_rss('url') ?></link>` to get the URL maybe?

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue most likely in these cases is the .htaccess file or any configuration files for the webserver.

In wordpress-admin, go to "Settings > Permalinks" and check the box for "Plain" like so:
[image: wordpress admin permalinks]

When you save, you can try if the links works. If they don't work, then there is an issue in wordpress and not the server. If it works, then try to put the "Plain" to the same setting as you had before and it will again generate a new .htaccess file and then maybe it will work. And if that doesnt work, then the issue is in the configuration of the webserver/hosting (apache2, nginx etc.)

Comment: I will try these steps! Thank you.